# How to access files and folders from pulled docker image

Tags: azure, docker, azure-appservice, azure-container-registry

this might be a trivial question but i researched a lot about it and couldn't find a clear answer.

I pulled a docker image from the docker hub and want to deploy on Azure Container Registry and connect it to an App Service. However, before I do so, I need to change the configuration in the files of the image. e.g, add elements to themes.xml.

Is there a way I can access these image folders and files to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Docker save Command:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

After you've made your changes, you can save the files back to an Image with the Docker load Command:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/

Hope that helps!

Comment: I will try that Benjamin and update you. Thanks!